# How to get a Context Handle from an access token

Tags: security, winapi

You can call [QuerySecurityContextToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379355(v=vs.85).aspx)() to obtain an access token from a context handle. I'd like to go the other way: given an access token like the one returned from [LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) I'd like to get a context handle. Can anyone tell me whether this is possible and, if so, how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: no, this is not possible. because `CtxtHandle` more than token. for get it you need or call `AcceptSecurityContext` (server side) or `InitializeSecurityContext` (client side)

Comment: Presumably you could impersonate the token and then call `InitializeSecurityContext` etc., as far as I know there's nothing preventing you from being both the "server" and the "client".  I can't see that there's any point, mind you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This seems to be something one doesn't do, probably because you can accomplish the same things with both APIs (SSP and Logon) - impersonation, for example. I was hoping to find a simple way to marry the two worlds. Thanks again.